# nginx "500 internal server error" on large request

Tags: nginx

I am sending a 14K request to my backend through nginx and I get the following error:

```
500 Internal Server Error
```

I am running `nginx 1.6.2` and if I send my request directly to my backend, everything works fine and the request takes about 3-4 seconds round trip.

This is my nginx config:

```
$ cat /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
events {
  worker_connections  1024;
}
http {
proxy_temp_path /tmp/nginx;

upstream my_servers {
   server <server1>:9000 down;
   server <server2>:9000 down;
   server <server3>:9000 down;
   server <server1>:9001;
   server <server2>:9001;
   server <server3>:9001;

}

server {
  access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log combined;

  listen 9080;
  location / {
     proxy_pass http://my_servers;
  }
}
}
```

Any idea on what is going on? I can't be hitting any default timeouts at 3-4 seconds I assume?

BTW, when I tried looking at the access log file, it was empty.

Comment: What is your programming language?

Comment: @Rafael I am writing the backend in Go, but how does that matter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue was related to permissions for `client_body_temp_path` as described here:

https://wincent.com/wiki/Fixing_nginx_client_body_temp_permission_denied_errors